# Image will not load when trying to call it up from from local JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I was able to bring in data dynamically from a local JSON file I created in RN.  However, when I went back and inserted an image for each profile so that it can be displayed dynamically with their profile info, the app broke saying "The  component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using ".
I am using a background for all of the profiles already, so I really don't understand what it is saying, since the images I inputted in the JSON file would be a profile image for each character.  Am I even following the proper format to call up an image?  Any help would be appreciated.

This is how I have my JSON File set up:

```
  const characters = [
      { id: "1", name: "Homer Simpson", occupation: "Nuclear Safety Inspector", 
        url:
          "https://assets.fxnetworks.com/cms/prod/shows/the-simpsons/photos/simpsons-sidebar/character-facts/Homer/swsb_character_fact_homer_288x763.png"
       },
      { id: "2", name: "Marge Simpson", occupation: "Stay-at-home mom", url:
      "https://assets.fxnetworks.com/cms/prod/shows/the-simpsons/photos/simpsons-sidebar/character-facts/Homer/swsb_character_fact_homer_288x763.png"},
      { id: "3", name: "Bart Simpson", occupation: "Student", url:
      "https://assets.fxnetworks.com/cms/prod/shows/the-simpsons/photos/simpsons-sidebar/character-facts/Homer/swsb_character_fact_homer_288x763.png" },
      { id: "4", name: "Lisa Simpson", occupation: "Student", url:
      "https://assets.fxnetworks.com/cms/prod/shows/the-simpsons/photos/simpsons-sidebar/character-facts/Homer/swsb_character_fact_homer_288x763.png" },
      { id: "5", name: "Maggie Simpson", occupation: "Baby", url:
      "https://assets.fxnetworks.com/cms/prod/shows/the-simpsons/photos/simpsons-sidebar/character-facts/Homer/swsb_character_fact_homer_288x763.png" }

 export default characters;
```

This is how I am bringing it in:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Button,
  ImageBackground
} from "react-native";
class CharacterProfiles extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "The Simpsons",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#53b4e6"
    },
    headerTintColor: "#f6c945",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { item } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    return (
      <View>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://backgrounddownload.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/simpsons-clouds-background-5.jpg"
          }}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        >
          <Image>{item.url}</Image>
          <Text>Name: {item.name}</Text>
          <Text>Occupation: {item.occupation}</Text>
          <Button
            title="Character Directory"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("CharacterDirectory")}
          />
          <Button
            title="Homepage"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
          />
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default CharacterProfiles;
```

Comment: Could we see the content of <Image /> component ?

Comment: @florian It is just a png image of each character.  If you look at my json file, you can copy and paste it to see the image. Not sure if that us what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I meant the content of <ImageBackground /> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way as you've already done with your `ImageBackground` component, you need to use the `source` attribute to assign the URL of an `Image`. You can see examples of this in more detail in React Native's [Image component documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html).

```
<Image
  source={{uri: item.url}}
/>
```

Including the source URL in the content of the `<Image>` tag as text will have no effect. Doing this would essentially be equivalent to writing the following in HTML:

```
<img>https://example.com/myImage.png</img>
```

You're getting the warning about placing content on top of the image because React Native thinks you're trying to superimpose the URL *as text* on the image. Since HTML `<img>` elements can't do this, neither can the `Image` component.

Comment: initially tried using the source attribute within JSON, but that did not work.  However, your explantation worked and now it makes sense. Thank you again.